# divide an array to create multidimensional array

Tags: ruby, arrays

I'm looking for a method to divide a one dimensional array by a number n to create a multidimensional array with each element having (at most) length n.
For example

```
[1,2,3,4,5,6] / 3
```

should result in:

```
[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]
```

Answer (score 5):

This should do it...

```
chunkedArr = arr.each_slice(3).to_a;
```

Comment: I knew it was something easy. Thanks.

Comment: @pguardiario I couldn't get it to work in CodePad.org and I'm not a Ruby guru, is it working for you?

Comment: More fun: `class Array; def /(n); each_slice(n).to_a; end; end` :)